# Pagebreak in \parbox

Tags: page-breaking, parbox

is there a possibility to allow pagebreaks within a `\parbox` environment? Here's the example

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfpageheight=10cm

\begin{document}
\centering
\parbox{5cm}{
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
}

\end{document}
```

that produces no pagebreak:
[image]
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
It's used to define yet another environment

```
\newcommand{\solpart}[2][1]%
{\mysolpointsadd{#1}\bigbreak%
{\small $\triangleright$}
\parbox[t]{0.8\textwidth}{#2}%
\hfill [\num{#1}]}
```

that will allow the editor to add some points to a *partial solution* and produce a little arrow at the beginning.

Comment: Not with a `\parbox`. Can you please give some context on how this would be used?

Comment: You simply need to remove the parbox from your \solpart definition (which seems to be a command not an environment) define it instead as a one-item list with the triangle as the list item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boxes always prevent page breaking. You want a one-item list here. You could adjust the list parameters to get exactly the spacing you need but something like this, where the first item is your original code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\solpart}[2][1]%
{\mysolpointsadd{#1}\bigbreak%
{\small $\triangleright$}
\parbox[t]{0.8\textwidth}{#2}%
\hfill [\num{#1}]}

\def\mysolpointsadd#1{}
\def\num#1{#1}

\newcommand{\solpartb}[2][1]%
{{\par\mysolpointsadd{#1}\bigbreak%
\list{\rlap{\makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-\labelwidth-\labelsep]%
           {\kern-10pt{\small $\triangleright$}\hfill[\num{#1}]}}}%
{\leftmargin.1\textwidth\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
\item\relax#2\endlist}}
\begin{document}


\solpart{\lipsum[1]}

\solpartb{\lipsum}

\solpartb{\lipsum}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Rather unpleasant behavior: For `\solpart{\lipsum} \\ \solpart{lipsum}`, the second partial solution will be in indented and will have the right numbers in brackets not aligned (`#1`)

Comment: Yes, excuse me. It should be `\solpart{\lipsum} \solpart{lipsum}`. Nevertheless, the unwanted intending behavior still occurs.

Comment: @EricScöerg oops you caught me out by using a command not an environment so there is a group missing, look again in a minute...

Comment: @EricScöerg try now, sorry.

Comment: Like a charm. Thank your for your help.

Comment: Note: `\mysolpointsadd{#1}` adds the argument `#1` to some variable `v`. The way `\solpartb` is defined, I guess it's some sort of local variable and the addition outside the environment does not work. To fix simply call the function `\mysolpointsadd{#1}` in the "outer bracket", i.e.:

`\newcommand{\solpartb}[2][1]%
{\mysolpointsadd{#1}{\par\bigbreak%
\list{\rlap{\makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-\labelwidth-\labelsep]%
           {\kern-10pt{\small $\triangleright$}\hfill[\num{#1}]}}}%
{\leftmargin.1\textwidth\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
\item\relax#2\endlist}}`